# Trying to figure out what's wrong with my return in my list function

Tags: java

```
public class Linked {
    static class Node {
        public Node (double item, Node next) { this.item = item; this.next = next; }
        public double item;
        public Node next;
    }
    int N;
    Node first;         

    public int posofLastNine () {
        if(first != null) {
            int index = 0;
            int indexTemp = 0;          
            for (Node x = this.first; x != null; x=x.next) {
                if (x.item == 9.0)
                    indexTemp = index;
                index++;
            }
            index -= 1;
            if (this.first.item == 9.0)
                return index;
            if (indexTemp == 0)
                return -1;
            return index - indexTemp; 
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

The point is to return the last index in a list that is 9. That is `0,1,9,9,10` would return `3`. The issue is, it needs to return `-1` if a `9` does not exist. I cannot figure out what's wrong in my code that's preventing it. I cannot add a function or add to parameters. But that's the only issue.

Comment: A detailed explanation is required with input and output

Comment: What is `first`?  How does it differ from `this.first`?

Comment: There is no input. The parameters must be empty. I can give you a test function. In a list that's [20,30,40,50], it returns [-2] and not [-1]. 9 is not in the list so it needs to output -1.

Comment: *The list* is the input.

Comment: I know. That is the test. Tried to provide an example to see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses variables and classes that you have not shown us, so I can't discern what's going on there. Please provide more information if you want specific help.

To get the last index of a specific element in an array (or list), the easiest way is to simply iterate backwards through the array. Return the first element that matches your parameters. If the whole array is traversed and no dice, return -1.

Here is an example with `int[]`:

```
public static int indexOfLastNine(int[] arrayIn) {
    for (int i = arrayIn.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (arrayIn[i] == 9) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Edit**

If we have to use your specific type of Linked list, here is an implementation that will work. Please note that this assumes the last node in the `Linked` list points to `null`.

```
public int posOfLastNine() {
    int lastNineIndex = -1;
    int currentNodeIndex = 0;
    Node currentNode = first;
    while (true) {
        if (currentNode == null) {
            break;
        }
        if (currentNode.item == 9.0) {
            lastNineIndex = currentNodeIndex;
        }
        currentNodeIndex++;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    return lastNineIndex;
}
```

Comment: public class Linked {

 static class Node {

  public Node (double item, Node next) { this.item = item; this.next = next; }

  public double item;

  public Node next;

 }

 int N;

 Node first;

This is all that's been left out

Comment: I also cannot use arrayIn or length. No functions or methods.

Comment: Could you please update the question itself with your entire class?

Comment: I just fixed it

Comment: I've tested it myself and it seemed to work fine. What tests are you running? Please provide more information.

Comment: Every test fails. For example testPositionOfLastNine (4, "9 11 21 31 41");

Comment: @emcioermcvorm, this test _`testPositionOfLastNine (4, "9 11 21 31 41");`_ expects the last index of 9 in array [9 11 21 31 41] to be 4?  it should be 0, no?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the logic to detect the last index of `9.0` is overcomplicated.

It could be refactored like this:

- remove null check for `first`
- set resulting index to -1 immediately
- remove redundant checks after the loop
- always return calculated `result`

```
    public int posofLastNine () {
        
        int result = -1;
        int index = 0;
        
        for (Node x = this.first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            if (x.item == 9.0) {
                result = index;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Test code:

```
    public static boolean test(int pos, String data) {
        if (null == data || data.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return -1 == pos;
        }
        
        String[] s = data.split("\\s");
        Node head = null;
        
        if (s.length > 0) {
        
            head = new Node(Double.parseDouble(s[0]), null);
            Node curr = head;
            for (int i = 1; i < s.length; i++) {
                Node next = new Node(Double.parseDouble(s[i]), null);
                curr.next = next;
                curr = next;
            }
        }
        
        Linked linked = new Linked();
        linked.N = pos;
        linked.first = head;
        return linked.N == linked.posofLastNine();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(test(-1, null));
        System.out.println(test(-1, ""));
        System.out.println(test(0, "9 11 14 31"));
        System.out.println(test(-1, "8 11 14 31")); // no 9
        System.out.println(test(3, "9 11 9 9 14 16"));
    }
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
true
true
```